# Node Redis Callback on PubSub

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

Why can't I have a callback with PubSub pattern design in Node Redis?

For instance:

```
server.publish("someChanel", someData, function(response) {
   // response should come back from client
});

client.on('message', function(channel, data, callback) {
   // Do stuff with data
   // Return data to callback
   callback(someNewData);
});
```

This obviously fails as `callback` is not defined.

Comment: @JamesSumners a more detailed answer is appreciated

Comment: Put your "callback" within the parent context of the message event handler -- https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md#you-dont-know-js-scope--closures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redis connection will emit events, so when you register `client.on('message'` every time there is a message, `function(channel, data)` will trigger. Inside that function, you can do anything, including call a different function.

E.g

```
function YourCallBackFn (err, data) {
    // do something with data
}

server.publish("someChanel", someData, function(response) {
   // response should come back from client
});

client.on('message', function(channel, data) {
   // Do stuff with data
   // Return data to callback
   YourCallBackFn(null, data);
});
```

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I want the `server` which is running on a different computer, to receive the callback

Comment: Okay that's what I thought. I'd need to have bi-directional communication between two different servers. What's my options?

Comment: Well it depends on your requirements. Think about what happens in a chat room, to have communication between 2 specific members, they have to know who the other person is. Therefore, in your case, each message must identify the sender. After that, it's a matter of writing the logic to inspect each message, verify sender identity and message type, and executing the appropriate action. Both servers will need to publish and listen for messages.

Comment: Makes sense. In my context, a client would need to verify something with a server through this Redis connection. So they would send some packet, and the server would send back a response. Does this mean I need to have pub/sub on both sides to send confirmation back?

Comment: Yes, both would need to be listening and publishing back and forth.

Comment: There should be a feature available for such a back and forth communication. This seems like such a simple action where a client sends a packet for processing, and the server returns the response ...

Comment: Why not just use http when you need 1 to 1 client-server communication?

Comment: Because I want to keep the connection open; I'm thinking of switching to Node-IPC?

Comment: That would would work, but both parties would still need to listen and emit I believe.

Comment: Use websockets, something like PieSocket.com is good fit for bidirectional comunication